# How to create an Amazon harware virtual machine (HVM) AMI from scratch?

Tags: amazon-ec2

All the instructions I find online start with an existing AMI, but I would like to create an AMI (Amazon Machine Image) from scratch using HVM (Hardware virtual machine) instead of PV (Paravirtualazation).
I would like to build or create new HVM AMI for montavista linux.
I did not find any existing public AMI available for montavista linux operating system.
SO i need to create new HVM-AMI from scratch. Could you please anyone share the process of creating HVM AMI or point to existing AMI for montavista linux if available.

Comment: You can find it [here](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/AWS/AWS_Tips/AWS_Management/AWS_10.shtml) a step by step post to create an AMI from scratch

Comment: Thank you for you reply.   The link you have shared is for PV AMI where we will use AKI and pv grub and i have tried this already. I would like to know same kind of steps to create HVM AMI .